# Emgu.CV to make an .avi

Tags: c#, emgucv, avi

I am using **Emgu.CV** library for object detection and 
worrying if it is possible to save my **.bmp** image as a frame to **.AVI** with this library.
I found VideoWriter class but pls give some examples or links.

I appreciate any ideas and give marks^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting it all together? Here's my take on the VideoWriter:

```
//VideoWriter vw = new public VideoWriter(string fileName, int fps, int width, int height, bool isColor);
VideoWriter vw = new VideoWriter("test.avi", 30, 500, 500, true);
//Then write your frame
vw.WriteFrame(frame);
```

I'm not sure about the WriteFrame() method yet. Check out the [link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/fc05f588-4769-c79d-ef5b-cfe9926701ea.htm) to it.

Answer (score 0):

Emgu CV is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the OpenCV image processing library. This is a very powerfull and easy tool if you want to process images or create video.
Here is the link for more details:
 http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp

With this tool you can create an avi video providing frames from Kinect RGB camera.